# WPF, TreeViewItem, how to not show contextMenu according to dependency property?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a treeview using the following style:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="itemTemplate" DataType="{x:Type AttCatalog:AttachmentCatalogModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Tag="{Binding Guid}">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu>
                    <MenuItem Header="New Item"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Move to..." />
                    <MenuItem Header="Delete" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
        </TextBlock>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<TreeView x:Name="tree" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="216" BorderThickness="0,0,1,0" Background="#FFFBFBFB" IsEnabled="{Binding IsEnabled}" ItemsSource="{Binding Catalogs}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource itemTemplate}" TreeViewItem.Expanded="OnExpandItemHandler" Margin="0,0,0,241" SelectedItemChanged="tree_SelectedItemChanged">
```

you can see TextBlock Tag binding a Guid property, my question is, how to do that when this Guid is empty (00000-00000000-00000), not show the contextMenu?

Comment: Add a Trigger in TextBlock.Trigger's which will check Tag Property to null & set its ContextMenu to null. Or also you can use converter which will be binded to ContextMenu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your context menu, bind the visibility to the Guid, and treat it with a converter  =>

```
<ContextMenu Visibility="{Binding Element=Guid, 
                          Converter={StaticResource GuidToVisibilityConverter}}">
      <MenuItem Header="New Item"/>
      <MenuItem Header="Move to..." />
      <MenuItem Header="Delete" />
</ContextMenu>
```

In your converter, you can treat your Guid value the way you want, to either return Visibility.Visible or Visibility.Hidden, depending on the value.

You can find more information on converters [here.](http://www.wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)

Hope that helped !